# "dreaded diamond" with polymorphism

Tags: c++, virtual

I have the following code:

```
class Base
{
    public:
        virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class BaseImpl : public virtual Base
{
    public:
       virtual void doSomething() {
       // something
       }
};

class BaseDerived: public virtual Base
{
    public:
       virtual void doSomething2() = 0;
};

class BaseDerivedImpl: public BaseImpl, public BaseDerived
{
    public:
       virtual void doSomething2(){
       // sonething2
       }
};
```

Then I have

```
Base* b = new BaseImpl();
b->doSomething();          // fatal error at this line (not in the method, but in the method invocation)
```

The problem is that it even does not go into the function.

Is it something wrong with using such hierarchy?

Comment: Your code compiles [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/yJL1f$29). What compiler are you using?

Comment: Yes it is compiled. gcc(4.7.2). I have runtime error

Comment: What you have doesn't even use BaseDerived or BaseDerivedImpl - should your declaration be Base*b = new BaseDerivedImpl; instead?  Regardless that works as well.

Comment: @user14416: I don't say any [run-time error either](http://liveworkspace.org/code/yJL1f$35). Are you showing the real code?

Comment: Why is the compiler not complaining on instantiating an abstract class ?

Comment: @AshRj: Because `BaseImpl` is not abstract

Comment: obviously, it is `// something` which breaks :)

Comment: Andy Prowl No, It is very close to real code. The function without arguments, the same inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: nothing's wrong with *diamond* as you instantiate `BaseImpl` - there is no diamond there, it's single inheritance. show us `//something`

Comment: @AndyProwl Ok. (`dosomething` is not a pure virtual function in `BaseImpl`).

Comment: In the line `class BaseDerivedImpl: public BaseImpl, public BaseDerived` does replacing `public BaseDerived` with `public virtual BaseDerived` fix the problem?

Comment: @Zadirion No, the same. What should the difference be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OP ignores the comments, let me answer the question here:

> Is it something wrong with using such hierarchy?

No, nothing is wrong. This is the standard way how to solve the 'dreaded diamond' issue (which isn't actually all that dreadful).

However, the diamond doesn't even come to play in this example:

```
Base* b = new BaseImpl();
```

`BaseImpl` is derived directly from `Base` so you have standard single inheritance. Your code behaves the same as if `BaseDerived` and `BaseDerivedImpl` were not defined at all. You can comment them out, and the app will still crash.

Then you call `doSomething` on this instance and it crashes. The implementation of `doSomething` is as follows:

```
// something
```

Thus, my conclusion is that `// something` results with crash, but it is impossible to tell without seeing the implementation of that method.

Comment: And note that the "dreaded diamond" is only dreaded by those who haven't taken a minute or two to see how it works. It's not hard...

Comment: I wouldn't blame the OP for that, though. Literature is full of blindly repeated screaming about 'dreaded diamond' that many people don't even want to know about details. Sure, you can shoot your foot off with it, but it is not black magic